# php new session created if needed

Tags: php, session

I would like create header on my php files because I need to transfer variables from one page to another without any security. Just transfer variables. 
What I need to do is check if session exist (is created) add variables to session variables. If is not set then create session and add variables

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{   
    session_start();
    require_once '../../file.php';
    $session = $conn -> prepare("SELECT name1, name2 FROM table_name where status = 'ok'");
    $session -> execute();
    $row = $session -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo 'session created'. "<br>";

    $_SESSION['name1'] = $row['name1];
    $_SESSION['name2'] = $row['name2'];  
}
else
{
    if(isset($_SESSION)) {
        // do something else
        echo 'session set';
        echo $_SESSION['name1'] . "<br>";
        echo $_SESSION['name2'] . "<br>";
    };
}
```

But my query is only on first step.

Comment: session_start(); must be before anything else, even a comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`session_start()` must be before any actions with session.

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['name1']) || !isset($_SESSION['name2'])) {
    /* ... */
} else {
    /* ... */
}
```